# Literate Programming in Base 26

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, base-conversion

Your task is to convert non-empty strings - between strings using the 26 letters, and programs, which are strings of bytes, where each byte has 256 possible values. You should use the same codepage your answer is written in for the possible values of bytes.

You need to do the following to do the conversion:

- Convert the letters to numbers `1-26`.
- Treat it as a base 26 [bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) number to convert it to a positive integer.
- Convert it to base 256 using `1-256`, again using bijective numeration.
- Turn it to bytes, where `i` turns to the byte with value `i-1`.

For example, for the string `hello`, you start with converting it to `[8, 5, 12, 12, 15]`, then you evaluate \$15 + 12\cdot26 + 12\cdot26^2 + 5\cdot26^3 + 8\cdot26^4 = 3752127\$. Then you convert \$3752127 = 191 + 64\cdot256 + 57\cdot256^2\$, so the answer is `[56, 63, 190]`.

**However**, you dislike gibberish. You want your code to be a concatenation of English words. You can't do that directly in your code, so instead you'll do that in its base26 representation.

### Rules

- Your code, when converted to base 26 using bijective numeration, has to be a concatenation of English words from [this wordlist](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/d0736d492489198e4f9d650c7ab4143bc14c1e9e/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt), with 1 or 2 letter words removed, except for `a, i, of, to, in, is, on, by, it, or, be, at, as, an, we, us, if, my, do, no, he, up, so, pm, am, me, go, ok, hi`.
- You can choose whether you want your input to have lowercase or uppercase letters, but it has to be consistent.
- Your input has to be a string, an array of characters or an array of bytes - you can't take an array of numbers from `1` to `26`, for example.
- Your output has to be a string, an array of characters, an array of bytes, or an array of numbers from `0` to `255`.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.
- If your language uses a base which isn't 256 then use that base, as long as it isn't a power of 26. If it is that language can't compete.

### Test cases

```
input string -> array of bytes
hi -> [216]
iw -> [0, 0]
sr -> [0, 255]
cat -> [7, 25]
crxq -> [255, 0]
cshl -> [255, 255]
cshm -> [0, 0, 0]
hello -> [56, 63, 190]
helloworld -> [39, 138, 176, 111, 2, 107]
apple -> [10, 110, 12]
loremipsumdolorsitamet -> [81, 108, 15, 236, 169, 234, 61, 72, 24, 166, 102, 147, 49]
```

### Scoring

Your score is the length of your program, encoded in base 26. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Please show an example of how to apply the first rule: some code and what the code looks like converted to base 26 using bijective numeration.

Comment: Please also explain why \$57\cdot256^2 + 64\cdot256 + 191\$ yields `[56, 63, 190]` rather than `[57, 64, 191]`. Does that imply that byte 255 becomes `254`?

Comment: Have you solved this yourself yet? From an initial attempt, this seems hard. Writing a program that meets the spec is relatively easy; modifying it to have a ‘literate’ reverse translation seems really hard.

Comment: If my programs contains non-letters, how do I represent them using base 26?

Comment: @doubleunary \$57\cdot 256^2 + 64\cdot256+191\$ yields `[56,63,190]` because in bijective numeration the digits are 1–256, so we subtract 1 to get bytes. See the last step.

Comment: @NickKennedy no, I haven't

Comment: @corvus_192 regardless of your program containing letters, you look at its bytes, and perform the procedure in reverse to get the base 26 representation. For example, if your program has bytes `[56, 63, 190]` then its base 26 is `hello`.

Comment: Does "an array of bytes" mean we may take a list of integer ordinals? (e.g. [99, 97, 116] in place of "cat".)

Comment: The requirement to convert to base 256 _using 1-256_ seems artificial. In my book, base 10 uses 10 numerals with values between 0-9 and base 256 uses 256 numerals with values between 0-255.

Comment: @doubleunary without using a bijective system a program would have the same value as itself with any or all leading zero-bytes removed, but these are clearly different programs.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 23

The bijective base \$26\$ program as words:

```
yrs seo dts i am a be in cpu sap
```

The Jelly code:

```
ÑÞ²¶O_96ḅ26ḃ⁹’
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wxMPzDm06tM0/3tLs4Y5WIyDR/Khx56OGmf///1fKACrKVwIA)**

Raw bytes as integers \$[1,256]\$:

```
[17, 21, 131, 128, 80, 96, 58, 55, 213, 51, 55, 232, 138, 254]
```

Converted from base \$256\$:

```
346505452333233856289746614520574
```

Converted to bijective base 26:

```
[25, 18, 19, 19, 5, 15, 4, 20, 19, 9, 1, 13, 1, 2, 5, 9, 14, 3, 16, 21, 19, 1, 16]
```

As characters, and then with spaces added to show the dictionary words used:

```
yrsseodtsiamabeincpusap
yrs seo dts i am a be in cpu sap
```

See [this process](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/T4VHTmsMzvB7ubFF4uKP1UeNOCKvZyAzM2N19eEYiiBVtomOuY2igY2ioY2isY2iiY2imY2ihY2QYe3Tyw53TvP///690eOLheYc2HdrmH29pBjQMaMSOZqCJjxpmKgEA) starting with the Jelly code.

#### How?

The first part, up to the `¶` is filler to ensure we get a valid intermediate string, the `¶` is equivalent to a newline and separates Links, and execution of Jelly programs start at the final Link. Since the final Link (`O_96ḅ26ḃ⁹’`) is not calling the previous one (`ÑÞ²`) and the full program parses without error, the final Link is called with an input of the input string as a list of characters:

```
O_96ḅ26ḃ⁹’ - Link: list of characters
O          - ordinals
 _96       - subtract 96 from each
    ḅ26    - convert from base 26
       ḃ⁹  - convert to bijective base 256
         ’ - decrement each
```

---

I also tried these suffixes (some will only work with upper case input):

```
¶O%32ḅ26ḃ⁹’
¶O%48ḅ26ḃ⁹’
¶O%64ḅ26ḃ⁹’
¶O_64ḅ26ḃ⁹’
¶Oạ64ḅ26ḃ⁹’
¶Oạ96ḅ26ḃ⁹’
```

There are many more that could be tried (like using unused code-page entires like `q` to create a new Link, or making a single Link that has some sort of no-op at the start etc.), so there may be terser out there.

Comment: Very nice. Did you brute force this or was there another way? I tried using four letter words working from the right but found I was exponentially increasing the length of the code and was never going to have a completely literate answer.

Comment: Brute force, effectively adding bytes in front of `¶O_96ḅ26ḃ⁹’` by starting with \$155122069311789175973382910\$ and adding \$256^{11}\$ until the bijective base \$26\$ string was valid (by recursively removing words).

Comment: In the explanation it's supposed to be "convert to bijective base 256", not 26, right?

Comment: @CommandMaster yes, thanks!